# Running Script on GPS Fix

Tags: linux, python, gpsd

I am working on an embedded device which is designed to capture images and I want to make it time and location aware. The device is currently a raspberry pi 2 running Debian Jessie.

I have GPS set up through the Hardware UART, and that works well, also updating the NTP for when the device is offline.

I would like to minimize the user input though, and with that in mind I found a python library which uses shapefiles to take a given latitude and longitude and return the approximate timezone that location would fall into.

Since the device is turned off between locations, I would like to try and run a script when the device is started up and a GPS fix is established.

With ethernet there is the ifup system, is there such a thing with gpsd that can be set to run a python script when a GPS fix is first established?

Many Thanks

Comment: And `man -k gps` says ... and `apt-cache search gps` says ... Gosh this is hard!

Comment: Sarcasm aside, none of those actually helped me. I have GPS working fine, that is not the issue, what I am not sure about is does an option exist within the gps daemon to call a script on first fix. From what I can see nothing seams to exist, I can go the python route and determine how long a fix has been established for to determine if the fix is recent but if I can avoid having to consistently run a script I thought that would be far better.